# Unable to compile thrift on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, cassandra

I am trying to install cassandra and thrift in my PC. I have successfully installed cassandra. But while making (using "make" command) thrift I am getting the error below:

```
...............
.............
......Entering directory `/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/lib/erl'
for f in ../../test/AnnotationTest.thrift ../../test/BrokenConstants.thrift ../../test/ConstantsDemo.thrift ../../test/DebugProtoTest.thrift ../../test/DenseLinkingTest.thrift ../../test/DocTest.thrift ../../test/JavaBeansTest.thrift ../../test/ManyTypedefs.thrift ../../test/OptionalRequiredTest.thrift ../../test/SmallTest.thrift ../../test/StressTest.thrift ../../test/ThriftTest.thrift test/Thrift1151.thrift ; do \
      ../../compiler/cpp/thrift --gen erl -out test $f ; \
    done ; \
    touch .generated
[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/BrokenConstants.thrift:20] 64-bit constant "68719476736" may not work in all languages.

[ERROR:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/BrokenConstants.thrift:21] (last token was '9876543210987654321')
This integer is too big: "9876543210987654321"

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:41] 64-bit constant "10000000000" may not work in all languages.

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:173] 64-bit constant "1099511627775" may not work in all languages.

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:183] 64-bit constant "4294967295" may not work in all languages.

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:183] 64-bit constant "1099511627775" may not work in all languages.

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:183] 64-bit constant "281474976710655" may not work in all languages.

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:183] 64-bit constant "72057594037927935" may not work in all languages.

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:183] 64-bit constant "9223372036854775807" may not work in all languages.

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:192] 64-bit constant "4294967295" may not work in all languages.

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:192] 64-bit constant "1099511627775" may not work in all languages.

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:192] 64-bit constant "281474976710655" may not work in all languages.

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:192] 64-bit constant "72057594037927935" may not work in all languages.

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:192] 64-bit constant "9223372036854775807" may not work in all languages.

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:201] 64-bit constant "9223372036854775807" may not work in all languages.

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:208] 64-bit constant "9223372036854775807" may not work in all languages.

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:355] No field key specified for field1, resulting protocol may have conflicts or not be backwards compatible!

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:356] No field key specified for field2, resulting protocol may have conflicts or not be backwards compatible!

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:357] No field key specified for field3, resulting protocol may have conflicts or not be backwards compatible!

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:358] No field key specified for field4, resulting protocol may have conflicts or not be backwards compatible!

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:359] No field key specified for field5, resulting protocol may have conflicts or not be backwards compatible!

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:360] No field key specified for field6, resulting protocol may have conflicts or not be backwards compatible!

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:361] No field key specified for field7, resulting protocol may have conflicts or not be backwards compatible!

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:362] No field key specified for field8, resulting protocol may have conflicts or not be backwards compatible!

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:363] No field key specified for field9, resulting protocol may have conflicts or not be backwards compatible!

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:364] No field key specified for field10, resulting protocol may have conflicts or not be backwards compatible!

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:365] No field key specified for field11, resulting protocol may have conflicts or not be backwards compatible!

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:366] No field key specified for field12, resulting protocol may have conflicts or not be backwards compatible!

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:41] 64-bit constant "10000000000" may not work in all languages.

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:173] 64-bit constant "1099511627775" may not work in all languages.

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:183] 64-bit constant "4294967295" may not work in all languages.

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:183] 64-bit constant "1099511627775" may not work in all languages.

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:183] 64-bit constant "281474976710655" may not work in all languages.

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:183] 64-bit constant "72057594037927935" may not work in all languages.

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:183] 64-bit constant "9223372036854775807" may not work in all languages.

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:192] 64-bit constant "4294967295" may not work in all languages.

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:192] 64-bit constant "1099511627775" may not work in all languages.

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:192] 64-bit constant "281474976710655" may not work in all languages.

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:192] 64-bit constant "72057594037927935" may not work in all languages.

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:192] 64-bit constant "9223372036854775807" may not work in all languages.

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:201] 64-bit constant "9223372036854775807" may not work in all languages.

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:208] 64-bit constant "9223372036854775807" may not work in all languages.

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:355] No field key specified for field1, resulting protocol may have conflicts or not be backwards compatible!

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:356] No field key specified for field2, resulting protocol may have conflicts or not be backwards compatible!

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:357] No field key specified for field3, resulting protocol may have conflicts or not be backwards compatible!

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:358] No field key specified for field4, resulting protocol may have conflicts or not be backwards compatible!

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:359] No field key specified for field5, resulting protocol may have conflicts or not be backwards compatible!

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:360] No field key specified for field6, resulting protocol may have conflicts or not be backwards compatible!

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:361] No field key specified for field7, resulting protocol may have conflicts or not be backwards compatible!

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:362] No field key specified for field8, resulting protocol may have conflicts or not be backwards compatible!

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:363] No field key specified for field9, resulting protocol may have conflicts or not be backwards compatible!

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:364] No field key specified for field10, resulting protocol may have conflicts or not be backwards compatible!

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:365] No field key specified for field11, resulting protocol may have conflicts or not be backwards compatible!

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/DebugProtoTest.thrift:366] No field key specified for field12, resulting protocol may have conflicts or not be backwards compatible!

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/JavaBeansTest.thrift:38] No field key specified for blah, resulting protocol may have conflicts or not be backwards compatible!

[WARNING:/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/test/JavaBeansTest.thrift:38] No field key specified for blah, resulting protocol may have conflicts or not be backwards compatible!

./rebar get-deps
==> nicefloats (get-deps)
==> jsx (get-deps)
==> erl (get-deps)
./rebar compile
==> nicefloats (compile)
Compiled src/nicefloats.erl
==> jsx (compile)
./include/jsx_common.hrl:34: type jsx_opt() undefined
./include/jsx_common.hrl:66: type jsx_parser_result() undefined
./include/jsx_common.hrl:82: type eep0018_array() undefined
./include/jsx_common.hrl:82: type eep0018_object() undefined
./include/jsx_common.hrl:84: type eep0018_term() undefined
./include/jsx_common.hrl:85: type eep0018_key() undefined
./include/jsx_common.hrl:85: type eep0018_term() undefined
./include/jsx_common.hrl:91: type eep0018_string() undefined
./include/jsx_common.hrl:92: type eep0018_number() undefined
./include/jsx_common.hrl:100: type encoder_opt() undefined
./include/jsx_common.hrl:109: type decoder_opt() undefined
./include/jsx_common.hrl:117: type verify_opt() undefined
./include/jsx_common.hrl:123: type format_opt() undefined
make[3]: *** [all] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/lib/erl'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev/lib'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/USER/thrift-0.9.0-dev'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have downloaded thrift from the site.
My OS is Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS 32 bit

Comment: Please do not use pastebins in questions. Questions and answers on this site are meant to stay, but pastebins are automatically destroyed after some time. Also, you do not need to sign your posts as a signature is automatically inserted.

Comment: This is a [Thrift bug known since sept. 2011](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-1357) but still unresolved... :-(

Answer (score 2):

Workaround: disable erlang when configuring thrift:

```
./configure --without-erlang
make
...
```